# ArcGIS Portal Maps in CMV

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, arcgis-portal

Is there support for maps from Portal for ArcGIS inside the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV)?

If so, how should one reference a portal map?

Comment: this question will be deleted for incomplete information. please edit the original question and add more information. What portal (internal or agol? what is CMV? what method are you wanting to reference portal map?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear to me. If you want to know more about "CMV" check out the tag "configurable-map-viewer" that was correctly applied to this question. And the title says "ArcGIS Portal Maps" that is quite definitive as well.

Answer (score 2):

CMV does not currently support the webmap specification (ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS). There are some efforts in progress to add that capability.

You can of course use your same ArcGIS Server REST services that are referenced in your portal webmap directly in CMV.